# How to preserve < and > in element value with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this XML file I want to parse with simple XML in PHP :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <content>Whoa, <ducks>!</content>
</data>
```

I want to preserve the  in the content element, so I tried to HTML encode it :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <content>Whoa, &lt;ducks&gt;!</content>
</data>
```

But then SimpleXML give me this error :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Premature end of data in tag content
```

Then I tried URLencode :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    <content>Whoa%2C%20%3Cducks%3E!</content>
</data>
```

And it give me this instead :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 3: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: ducks
```

Here's my current PHP code, pretty simple, right?

```
$request = simplexml_load_string($_POST["data"]);
```

So, what's the correct way to parse that XML file while still keeping the special characters?

Comment: You encoded XML with &gt; and &lt; is valid and works. It sounds like here is an entity decode somewhere in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your values in CDATA

```
<title><![CDATA[Lorem ipsum]]></title>
```

Comment: Ok, that works, now I just need to figure out how to automatically adds CDATA to that element. Thanks!

Comment: The application that generates the xml file should be where it is added.

Comment: Cdata would be only a workaround in this case, not a fix. "<![CDATA[<ducks/>]]>", "<![CDATA[&lt;ducks/&gt;]]>" and "&lt;ducks/&gt;" all return the same text value.